# Determine file extension of an image that is missing an extension

Tags: php, image, file-extension

I have some images on my system that were saved without a file extension, they appear in the format of "FILENAME." (Note the period)

I am trying to use getimagesize(); but it is erroring out telling me that "Filename cannot be empty"

Here is a sample of the code I am using

```
    $contents = file_get_contents($localFile);

    $imageData = getimagesize($contents);
    // $imageData[2] will contain the value of one of the constants
    $mimeType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageData[2]);
    $extension = image_type_to_extension($imageData[2]);
```

Comment: Your images should have extensions ( e.g. GIF, JPG, PNG, etc. ). Also not all browsers might return MIME type back to PHP script so you are better off creating an array of allowable extensions ( e.g. $allowedExts = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png') ) then explode the filename of an image ( e.g. $tmp = explode(".", $filename) ) and check whether the uploaded file is an image using `in_array($tmp, $allowedExts)`. If it is then do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation: http://php.net/getimagesize
getimagesize() is expecting a filename as first parameter, not the contents of the image file.

Try:

```
$imageData = getimagesize($localFile);
// $imageData[2] will contain the value of one of the constants
$mimeType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageData[2]);
$extension = image_type_to_extension($imageData[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) expects a file name as the first argument